# What is an Admob Session?

Tags: android, admob

On the Admob console (https://apps.admob.com/#home), there is a section called "Analyse" with some session information.

What is this information? and why only some of my app have this session information? I did not add any special codes into these apps.

Also the number of impressions is about the same (for the apps with and without the session information)

[image: Session information]

[image: Session per app]

Comment: I have been wondering this myself. `ScreenView` vs `PageView` vs `Session`. They also all have their own `time` and `average time`.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions represent durations users spend interacting with your app.

According to [the docs](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3508177?hl=en):

**Sessions:** The total number of sessions for all of your linked apps. A session is the period of time a user interacts with an app. All usage data (Screen Views, Events, Ecommerce, etc.) is associated with a session.

**Avg. session duration:** The average duration of sessions for all of your linked apps.

**Users:** The sum of all active users of each of your linked apps during the requested time period.

Hope that helps